# Show limited no. of page links in codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display a limited no. of page links, say 5 out of 10 links,is there any known or tried and tested method in codeIgniter to achieve this.

so lets say user can right now see following links

```
prev, 1(selected), 2, 3, 4, 5... next
```

user clicks on, say 4, now he sees

```
prev... 3, 4(selected), 5, 6, 7...next
```

now he clicks on 7

```
prev... 6, 7(selected), 8, 9, 10...next
```

How can I do this in code igniter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u get your answer if not let me know......

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in [Pagination class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

find Pagination Class in Libraries folder and edit this variable:

```
var $num_links
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt Pagination class provided by codeIgniter. You can find it in user guide.

Define a start index variable in the function where u want to use pagination as zero.

```
public function pagination($start_index = 0)
```

{

```
  $result = $this->model->get_results($data); //this $data is the argument which you are passing to your model function. If you are using database to get results array.

  $items_per_page = 10;   //this is constant variable which you need to define

  $filtered_result = array_splice($result, $start_index, ITEM_PER_PAGE_USERS);

  $model['$filtered_result'] = $filtered_result;

  $total_rows = count($result);

  $model['page_links'] = create_page_links (base_url()."/controlelr_name/pagination",ITEM_PER_PAGE_USERS, $total_rows);

  $this->load->view('controller_name/view_file_name', $model);
```

}

```
 function create_page_links($base_url, $per_page, $total_rows) {

$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = $base_url;
$config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
$config['per_page'] = $per_page; 

$CI->pagination->initialize($config); 

return $CI->pagination->create_links();
```

}

This create page links function is a generic function.............for more explanation check [pagination](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) class from user guide......

Answer (score 0):

When you want to fixed the **pagination** page number you modify the `$num_links`:

```
$config['total_rows'] =100;
$config["num_links"] = 5;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
```

It shows like this:  << 2 3 4 5 6 7 >>