# pagination with codeigniter, other then index function

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have set rout as

```
$route['dog/(:any)']        = "dog/index/$1";  /// for single dog info
$route['dog/list']              = "dog/listing";   /// for dog list, display all dogs.
$route['dog/list/(:num)']       = "dog/listing/$1"; /// for pagination
```

single dog url is like dog/dogName-4.html

my controller is as

```
public function index()
{
    $dogInfo = $this->uri->segment(2);

    if ($dogInfo != "")
    {
        $dogDetails = explode('-', $dogInfo);

        $this->load->view('common/header',$header);
        $this->load->view('dog/dog_info', $content);
        $this->load->view('common/footer', $footer);
    }
    else
        redirect('welcome', 'location', 301);
}
public function listing()
{
    $this->load->library("pagination");
    $breed  = $this->input->get('breed');
    $gender = $this->input->get('gender');
    $state  = $this->input->get('state');
    $seller = $this->input->get('seller');

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "dog/list/";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->dogs->get_dog_list_count($breed, $gender, $state, $seller);
    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $content['details'] = $this->dogs->get_dog_list($config["per_page"], $page,$breed, $gender, $state, $seller);

    $content['paginatonLinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $content['total_dogs'] = $config['total_rows'];
    $content['cur_page'] = $page + 1;
    $content['total_pages'] = ceil($config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"]);

    $this->load->view('common/header');
    $this->load->view('dog/dog_list', $content);
    $this->load->view('common/footer', $footer);
}
```

The controller's index function is to display information about one dog, and listing function is for all the dogs,

I have to set pagination for listing function i did set all the required variables for pagination, pagination displaying the result as well

Found [134] Ads :: Page 1 of 27  1 2 3 >  Last ›

but when i click on the pagination 1 2 3 else on page it brings me to the index page.

I need to be on the listing function of the controller. please any one help me.

---

here is the updated code

the rout code is

```
$route['dog/list']      = "dog/listing";
$route['dog/list/(:num)']       = "dog/listing/$1";
$route['dog/(:any)']        = "dog/index/$1";
```

and here is the updated controller code

```
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "dog/list/";
    $config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->dogs->get_dog_list_count($breed, $gender, $state, $seller);
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a href="#" class="page_selected">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $this->load->model('DogsListing_model', 'dogs');
    $this->load->model('Breed_model', 'breeds');
    $content['breeds']  = $this->breeds->get_all_id_title();
    $content['details'] = $this->dogs->get_dog_list($config["per_page"], $page,$breed, $gender, $state, $seller);
    $content['search']  = array('breed' => $breed, 'gender' => $gender, 'state' => $state, 'seller' => $seller);
    $content['paginatonLinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $content['total_dogs'] = $config['total_rows'];
    $content['cur_page'] = $page + 1;
    $content['total_pages'] = ceil($config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"]);
```

Comment: What I can see you use the THIRD uri segment for page numbers. So it shouldnt be  $this->uri->segment(2) but $this->uri->segment(3) and $config["uri_segment"] = 3; ???

Comment: also if your urls end with .html then you probably has some htaccess rewrite. This might mess you up as well...

Comment: I need to know why paginated links goes to the index function of the controller. and what changes i can so that paginated links remain on the same page or listing function of the controller. here is the link if you want to visit the working site, [link](http://urpuppy.com/dog/list.html)

Comment: @Jtheman you are right, after making url like this`$this->uri->segment(3);` and `$config["uri_segment"] = 3;` also i rearrange the routs. it is working. but now my next problem is how can i send variable along with pagination like `/dog/list`/?seller=29 how i send this seller veriable. i have base url for pagination like `$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "dog/list/";` thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution of my question

first i have use `$this->uri->segment(3) and $config["uri_segment"] = 3;` i was using a wrong uri->segment for pagination. this solve my problem related to pagination.

my next part is i have to set variables for seller or search results with the pagination. for example i have the url `doglist.html/?seller=29` i need to embed pagination with this pagination. so that the result will be like `dog/list/3?breed=&gender=female&state=&submit2=Fetch` i have solve this issue with this line of code `$config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");` now my pagination with variables works fine.

Thanks to @jtheman and @Venkat, but mostly @jtheman for their contributings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any doubt related to [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519130/show-limited-no-of-page-links-in-codeigniter-pagination/13523440#13523440) check out this generalised function which i wrote as answer to another question.

Comment: yes part of my question was solved with the suggestion of @jtheman. pagination part solved, but now i want to know how can i handle url variables with pagination, how can i make the url to handle url variables. like i have a variavle `doglist.html/?seller=29` while pagination forms url like this `dog/list/3`.

Comment: Please anyone can help me, out this i need to make a url that can be used with pagination.

Comment: this url is work fine, `/dog/list/2/?seller=29` how can i set this url in pagination, while my base url like `$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "dog/list/";` how can i edit the base url.

Comment: which url u want it. /dog/list/2?seller=29 or /dog/list/2

Comment: thanks @venkat i want this url `http://urpuppy.com/dog/list/2?seller=29` it is working now. but when you click on 1 page it redirect to the home page why?