# Codeigniter Pagination and URI Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, pagination

I have a route in my config/routes file as follows:

```
$route['thing/(:num)'] = 'site/pages/$1';
```

And in my pagination config which is in `site/pages`, there are the following related options:

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "thing";
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
```

The above generates links correctly, as: thing/20, thing/40 (as I've given 20 per page config option) And the first page displays correctly with 20 links.

But when I click on the second page link, it returns a 404. When I go ahead and edit the url in the browser to /site/pages/20 or site/pages/40, it works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please show your actual code? Or, are you really using `thing` as the URL segment? I don't see why the links would say `page/X` if you have the base url set as "thing"... I'm pretty sure it would produce links like `thing/20`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Wesley, actually I forgot to replace page/20, page/40 with thing/20 and thing/40 while I was posting. I'll edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want to read the routed URI segment (the one that is actually in the URL). Because of your routing configuration, it would be the second segment:

```
$config["uri_segment"] = 2;
```

From the [docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html):

> The pagination function automatically determines which segment of your URI contains the page number. If you need something different you can specify it.

The pagination class assumes `3` (the default) by guessing `controller/method/param` where "param" is the method's first/only argument.

However, your routing has the page number in the second segment, so just set it to `2`.

Comment: Just like Walter's answer, didn't work. All the page links load only the first 20 rows.

Comment: Ah OK, then let's see the rest of your controller code, and how you're fetching data from the database. It sounds like you aren't *using* the page numbers/offsets correctly. This does fix the "404" issue right?

Comment: Yes, the 404 issue is fixed. The pagination links always load the first page.

Comment: My controller method goes like this:  $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "thing";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->things_model->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 20;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 2;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

  $data['teams'] = $this->things_model->get_things($config['per_page'], $page);
  $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

  //load views with data

Answer (score 0):

Check the great examples given in the codeigniter userguide, http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url("thing/");

$config["uri_segment"] = 2;
```

remember that 
uri segment is refered to the uri

Comment: Didn't work. Still, the page links all load the first 20 results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for any reference how to do pagination and at the same time with good routing to each page link please look into this [Pagination reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519130/show-limited-no-of-page-links-in-codeigniter-pagination/13523440#13523440) answer given by me for one of the question. I hope it will clear all your doubts.