# CodeIgniter Pagination, possible routing issue?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, routes

I'm trying to learn CodeIgniter and I'm having trouble with the pagination. I'm a complete newbie so I apologise if I've missed anything.

The pagination displays on my views fine, generates everything it should, but the pages give me a 404. I suspect it might have something to do with the routes or the uri_segment (though I've changed it to a whole bunch of numbers and nothing did the trick), but I'm not sure.

The URLs each page generates are /music3/music/20, /music3/music/40, etc.

Let me know if you need anything I haven't included.

Controller:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://moefoster.com/music3/music/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('Music');
$config['per_page'] = '20';
$config['num_links'] = '5';
$config['uri_segment'] = '2';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$data['music'] = $this->music_model->get_music($config['per_page'], $config['uri_segment']);
```

Model:

```
public function get_music($num = 20, $offset = 0, $slug = FALSE) {
    if ($slug === FALSE) {
        return $this->db->select('*')->from('Music')->limit($num, $offset)->order_by('Release', 'desc')->get()->result_array();

    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('Music', $num, $offset, array('Track' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();

}
```

Routes:

```
$route['music'] = 'music';
$route['default_controller'] = "music";
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Comment: what is music3, is a folder where music controller resides ?

Comment: The project isn't at the root of my domain. /music3/ is the CodeIgniter directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use standard pagination :/ nevermind, pagination generated like this:

class / function / pagination num

URL BASE:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://moefoster.com/music/';
```

ROUTES:

```
$route['music'] = 'music';
$route['music/(:num)'] = 'music/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = "music";
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

but I use in backend, \libraries\My_Pagination.php

```
<?php
if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination
{
    var $offset = 0;
    var $pagination_selector = 'page';
    var $index_page;

    function MY_Pagination ()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        log_message('debug', "MY_Pagination Class Initialized");

        $this->index_page = config_item('index_page') != '' ? config_item('index_page') . '/' : '';
        $this->_set_pagination_offset();
    }

    function _set_pagination_offset ()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        if (strstr($CI->uri->uri_string(), $this->pagination_selector)) {
            $segments = $CI->uri->segment_array();
            foreach ($segments as $key => $value) {
                if ($value == $this->pagination_selector) {
                    $this->offset = $CI->uri->segment($key + 1);
                    $this->uri_segment = $key + 1;
                    $uri = $CI->uri->uri_string();
                    $pos = strpos($uri, $this->pagination_selector);
                    $this->base_url = '/'.$this->index_page . substr($uri, 0, $pos + strlen($this->pagination_selector.'/'));
                }
            }        
        }
        else {
            $this->offset = 0;
            $this->uri_segment = 0;
            $this->base_url = '/'.$this->index_page . $CI->uri->uri_string() . '/' . $this->pagination_selector.'/';        
        }    
    }
}
```

**Example controller**

```
 function somefunction($somevariable){
        $config['total_rows'] = Model_Admin::getCountClankyCategory($somevariable); 
        $config['per_page'] = 25;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '#START SOME HTML#';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '#END SOME HTML#';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '#START SOME HTML PAGINATION#';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '#END SOME HTML PAGINATION#';  
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);          
      $data['content'] =  Model_Admin::getAllClankyCategory($somevariable,$config['per_page'],$this->pagination->offset);
.....
}
```

**some example model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_Admin extends CI_Model {
  private static $db;

  function __construct() 
  {
    parent::__construct();
    self::$db = &get_instance()->db;
  }
static function getAllClankyCategory($cat,$num,$offset)  {   
     self::$db->where('#MYTYPE#',$cat);
      return self::$db->get('#SOMETABLE#',$num,$offset)->result_array();   
    }

static function getCountClankyCategory($cat) {
         return self::$db->count_all_results('#SOMETABLE#');
     }
```

then  if u use "some hard code routing", routes like, other u use without these routes

```
$route['admin/articles/cat/(:any)'] = "admin/cat/$1"; 
$route['admin/articles/cat/(:any)/(:num)'] = "admin/cat/$1/$2";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check one my previous answers on [Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519130/show-limited-no-of-page-links-in-codeigniter-pagination/13523440#13523440) which explains very well how to do pagination and how to take care urls perfectly.....